# Trigger a function when firebase notification receive while app is open

Tags: android, firebase

I have a question about firebase notification service. I send notification from firebase console it receive successfully and i user click on notification then i open "TrackinActivity", this work fine. But if user open app and stay on "TrackinActivity" and then firebase notification receive i want without any refresh in TrackinActivity a funtion is trigger in TrackinActivity. which change some values in TrackinActivity without refresh.

I mean in this function:

```
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}
```

i want to call a function of that tracking activity without refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you have to set a boolean variable in shared preference

for example `isActivityOpened = true`

set value `false` when you destroy  `"TrackinActivity"`  and set value `true` in `onCreate` of this activity

```
 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        if(isActivityOpened){//check sharedpreference

           //here send local broadcast message and receive in "TrackinActivity"
           //on receive method of local broadcast update some values in activity

        }else{

           //here start activity as usual 

        }
 }
```

for getting details about [local broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)